How to find mixed-strategy nash equilibrium payoff in this game?
Suppose there are 2 players. Each player chooses a non-negative integer $(0,1,2,\cdots)$. The players make their choices sequentially, with the second player observing the choice of the first player. Let $s_i$ be the integer chosen by player $i$, and let $a=\frac{s_1+s_2}{2}$ be the average of players' choices. According to the rules below, a winner is determined. Winner gets payoff 1 and loser gets payoff 0.
We are asked to solve for

all subgame-perfect equilibria
the possible equilibrium payoffs across all nash equilibria (pure and mixed)

When the winning rules are, respectively,

The player whose choice $s_i$ is closest to $\frac{2a}{3}$
The player whose choice $s_i$ is closest to $a$
The player whose choice $s_i$ is closest to $\frac{4a}{3}$

However, I'm having trouble finding the mixed-strategy nash equilibrium payoffs.
Here is what I have done:

If the winning rule is the player whose choice is closest to $\frac{2a}{3}$ wins, to find SPE, we do backward induction. Note that
\begin{align}
BR_2(s_1)=\begin{cases} \{0\}\;\text{if $s_1=0$}\\ \{0,\cdots,s_1-1\}\;\text{if $s-1\geq 1$} \end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, given $s_2=0$, $BR_1(s_2=0)=0$, this is a mutual best response; given $s_2>0,BR_1(s_2)=s_2-1$, but then the given $s_2$ is not a best response to $s_1$. Thus, SPE is $s_1=0, s_2=BR_2(s_1)$. Then the nash equilibrium payoff is $(0.5,0.5)$.

If the winning rule is the player whose choice is closest to $a$ wins, $BR_2(s_1)=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$. Given any $s_2$, since no matter what player 1 does, both players are equally close to $a$. Thus, SPE is $s_1=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}, s_2=BR_2(s_1)$. Then the nash equilibrium payoff is $(0.5,0.5)$.

If the winning rule is the player whose choice is closest to $\frac{4a}{3}$ wins, then $BR_2(s_1)=\{s_1+1,s_1+2,\cdots\}$. Given any $s_2$, no matter player 1 does, player 1 is going to lose. Thus, SPE is $s_1=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ and $s_2=BR_2(s_1)$. The nash equilibrium payoff is $(0,1)$.


I would appreciate help on how to find the mixed-strategy nash equilibrium payoff, and pointing out any mistakes in my solution (if mistakes exist).
